# zlib deflate and dynamic output buffer

Tags: c++, c, gzip, zlib, deflate

Ok, i remade my question a bit, i do not understand how TO properly deflate the content into the DYNAMIC buffer, who needs to be constantly reallocating. I re-wrote my code a bit, and it work ONLY if no reallocating of the buffer happens, so on the small amount of data, reallocating breaks somehow the output stream.

```
void test_deflate_dynamic(char*str)
{

if(store == NULL)  // first call to the function allocate some memory etc
    {   

        gzip_stream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
        gzip_stream.zfree = Z_NULL;
        gzip_stream.opaque = Z_NULL;

        result =  deflateInit(&gzip_stream,9);
        if(result!=Z_OK) { printf("bad\r\n"); exit(0); }


        total_buf_size =deflateBound(&gzip_stream,strlen(str));
        printf("d_bound_init=%d\r\n",total_buf_size);

        store = realloc(store,total_buf_size); // first allocation
        gzip_stream.avail_out = total_buf_size;

        gzip_stream.next_out = store;

        gzip_stream.avail_in = strlen(str)+1;
        gzip_stream.next_in = str;

        result = deflate(&gzip_stream,Z_NO_FLUSH);

    }

    else
    {

       gzip_stream.avail_in = strlen(str)+1;
       gzip_stream.next_in = str;
       int t_size;


        printf ("avail_out=%d\r\n",gzip_stream.avail_out);

        t_size = deflateBound(&gzip_stream,strlen(str));
        printf("d_bound=%d\r\n",t_size);
        total_buf_size += t_size;
        gzip_stream.avail_out = total_buf_size;
        store = realloc(store,total_buf_size);

        gzip_stream.next_out = store;

        result = deflate(&gzip_stream,Z_NO_FLUSH);


    }
}
```

As you can see i'm using the function `deflateBound` to detect how much more data i need to allocate, so first, is it correct to use deflateBound? Second, is the pointer which modified by `realloc` and then re-assigned to the `z_stream`, still points to the beginning of the data? So basically if i'm using multiple reallocations the end data is broken. End: How do i proper detect, how much data do i need to allocate for my output deflate buffer, and **is it correct to use the dynamic re-allocating buffer in the z_stream?**

Comment: What you are doing right or wrong also depends on how you call `test_deflate_dynamic()` and what you do with the data it yields. Therefore you have to post a complete program.

Answer (score 0):

`realloc` ensures the data is copied to the new location when the new size didn't fit into the old memory position. `calloc` just zeros the allocated memory, and doesn't copy over the old data. Therefore you must pass bigger values to `calloc`. You probably only need one call to `calloc` when you pass it that big numbers whereas `realloc` can accept smaller increments. Make sense?

Cheers

Comment: So i assume i can't use realloc with z_stream, since the buffer should be set only one time, so deflate will make the proper zipped content out of this buffer, i cant realloc it, right? It should be pre-allocated?

Comment: See my question again please, i made a lot of edits.